# What happens to the tangent space of a translated submanifold?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tangent-spaces

Let $(M,h)$ be a Riemannian space and given some $x_0\in M$, consider the geometric Riemannian sphere of radius $r$ centered at $x_0$, i.e.

$$S^r_h(x_0)=\{x\in M| d_h(x_0,x)=r\}.$$

Let $W_0$ be a constant vector tangent to $M$ s.t. $||W_0||<1$.  Let $S=S^r_h(x_0)+\varphi(r,x_0)$ and note that $x\in S^r_h(x_0)$ if and only if $x+\varphi(r,x_0)\in S$. Here $\varphi(s,x)$ is the flow of $W_0$, i.e., $\frac{d\varphi}{ds}=W_0(\varphi)$.

> One can say that $$T_{x+\varphi(r,x_0)}S=T_xS^r_h(x_0)+rW_0,$$ i.e. $T_{x+\varphi(r,x_0)}S$ is parallel to  $T_xS^r_h(x_0)$?

Practically it seems affirmative however I could not prove it.
Any comment?

By $T_xS^r_h(x_0)$ I mean the tangent space of $x$ and so on.

I am wondering what I am doing is technically correct?

Comment: How are you defining $S^r_h(x_0)+rW_0$? $M$ is not a vector space. It does not come with a built-in addition. (There is a way of defining what you are after, but once you understand that definition, you should find the proof you are after in it.)

Comment: @PaulSinclair. I thought that if I take $W$ small enough it could belong to the manifold $M$. Could you please say what is the way that you mentioned?

Comment: @PaulSinclair! I edited the question. I think it is correct now.

Comment: Actually, what I was thinking of in the first comment was parallel translation along a geodesic. If $v \in T_{x_0}M$, there is a unique geodesic $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0) =x_0$ and $\dot \gamma(0) = v$. One can then identify "$x_0 + tv$" with the point $\gamma(t)$. However, I was overlooking that you are trying to translate not $x_0$, but the points of $S_h^r(x_0)$. $v$ is not a vector in any of their tangent spaces, so the concept breaks down. I'll discuss the problems with your definition of "$W_0$" in my answer.

Comment: What is the motivation for this question, that is, why are you interested in translating submanifolds (in any sense of the word)? If you have a diffeomorphism $F : M \to M$, then for any point $p$ in a given submanifold $S$, the $F$ maps $S$ to $F(S)$ and pushes forward the tangent space $T_p S$ of $S$ at $p$ to $T_p F \cdot T_p S = T_{F(p)} F(S) \subset T_{F(p)} M$.

Answer (score 2):

You still have some problems in your post, but now it is clear to me that the problem is that you are being misled by your $\Bbb R^n$ intuition, and not just using a notational shorthand. This can indeed be stated in terms of flows, but not as you currently have it.

You describe $W_0$ as a "constant vector tangent to $M$". Since you now speak of its flows, apparently you are considering $W_0$ to be defined everywhere in $M$ (or at least on some neighborhood). But there is no such thing as a "constant" vector field. The tangent spaces $T_xM$ and $TyM$ for distinct points $x, y \in M$, are entirely separate vector spaces, with no intrinsic way of relating vectors in $T_xM$ to vectors in $T_yM$. What does "constant" mean when there is no relationship?

The most obvious way to fix it is simply to drop the word "constant", and take $W_0$ to be an arbitrary smooth vector field on some neighborhood of $x_0 \in M$ containing $S_h^r(x_0)$ satisfying $W_0 \ne 0$ everywhere (that $\|W_0\| < 1$ is not needed). That $W_0 \ne 0$ is crucial, as the flow $\varphi$ will be singular where $W_0 = 0$. But this is also why we can't just have $W_0$ defined on all $M$. There may not be a never-zero vector field on $M$. Quite famously, [you can't comb the hair on a sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

A second issue is that you are still thinking of $M$ itself as having an addition defined on it. "$S=S^r_h(x_0)+\varphi(r,x_0)$" and "$x+\varphi(r,x_0)\in S$" are non-sensical. There is no definition of "$+$" between the elements of $M$.

Fortunately, in this case what you are after is clear. $S = \varphi(S^r_h(x_0), r)$, the image of $S^r_h(x_0)$ under the mapping $\varphi_r : x \mapsto \varphi(r,x)$. (Note that the domain of $W_0$ must contain all of $S^r_h(x_0)$

Now we get to the result you want to show:
$$T_{x+\varphi(r,x_0)}S=T_xS^r_h(x_0)+rW_0$$
but again, it doesn't make sense, even after fixing the basepoint addition: $T_{\varphi_r(x)}S$ and $T_xS_h^r(x_0)$ are separate vector spaces. You cannot add anything to vectors in $T_xS_h^r(x_0)$ to get a vector in $T_xS_h^r(x_0)$, because no such addition is defined. Now $S = \varphi_r(S^r_h(x_0))$, and you can show that because $W_0 \ne 0$ anywhere, $\varphi_r$ is not singular. Therefore $$T_{\varphi_r(x)}S = d\varphi_r(T_xS^r_h(x_0))$$